# Ldap Authentication via Glassfish 4 gives forbidden access

Tags: authentication, ldap, glassfish-4

When trying to login as a registered user in **LDAP Server**, wrong username or password redirect successfully to error page, However when they are correct it didn't grant the user the access with the following error:

**HTTP Status 403 - Forbidden**.

I'm coding my pages in **JSF**.

My **Glassfish** console [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJ5xQ.jpg).

My web.xml like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <security-role>
        <description>all the users with the role Admin</description>
        <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
    </security-role>

    <security-role>
        <description>all the users that are authenticated</description>
        <role-name>LOGGEDIN_USER</role-name>
    </security-role>

    <security-role>
        <description>all the users that are moderators/extended rights</description>
        <role-name>MODERATOR</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>SecurityConstraint</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Secured resources</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>LOGGEDIN_USER</role-name>
            <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
            <role-name>MODERATOR</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>ldapRealm</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/loginError.xhtml</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
</web-app>
```

My sun-web.xml has this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE sun-web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.0 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://www.sun.com/software/appserver/dtds/sun-web-app_3_0-0.dtd">
<sun-web-app error-url="">
    <context-root>/</context-root>
    <security-role-mapping>
        <role-name>LOGGEDIN_USER</role-name>
        <group-name>default</group-name>
    </security-role-mapping>
    <security-role-mapping>
        <role-name>MODERATOR</role-name>
        <group-name>moderatoren</group-name>
    </security-role-mapping>
    <security-role-mapping>
        <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
        <group-name>root</group-name>
    </security-role-mapping>
    <class-loader delegate="true"/>
    <jsp-config>
        <property name="keepgenerated" value="true">
            <description>Keep a copy of the generated 
                servlet class' java code.</description>
        </property>
    </jsp-config>
</sun-web-app>
```

Comment: I don't see anything JSF related in here

Comment: the problem isn't in the jsf itself so I didn't put it here

Comment: Then don't tag it with jsf. Tags are NOT for what you use but for what is an important part of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.
the problem was with the uppercase letters for roles in the web.xml